# Почему массив не изменяется?

Tags: javascript

Да, то, что я хочу, можно реализовать через return в функции, но меня волнует мой вопрос.

Почему arr не меняется при использовании функции?

```
function filterRange(arr, start, end) {
  arr = arr.filter(item => (item >= start && item <= end));
}

let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];

let filtered = filterRange(arr, 1, 4);

alert( filtered ); // 5, 3, 8, 1    
alert( arr );      // 5, 3, 8, 1
```

Comment: Вопрос не до конца понятен. В приведенном коде `filtered` будет равен `undefined`.

Comment: `return` нет---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function filterRange(arr, start, end) {
  // т.к. ссылка на объект является значением, ф-ция получает копию этой ссылки
  arr = arr.filter(item => (item >= start && item <= end));
  // arr = ... - меняет копию ссылки, из-за этого изменения и не видны снаружи;
  // в данном случае ссылке arr присваивается новый массив -
  // arr.filter(item => (item >= start && item <= end));
}

let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1]; // arr - ссылка на место в памяти где лежит массив [5, 3, 8, 1];

let filtered = filterRange(arr, 1, 4); // ссылка передается аргументом в функцию;

alert( filtered ); // 5, 3, 8, 1    
alert( arr );      // 5, 3, 8, 1
```

Дело в следующем... Аргументы ф-ции передаются по значению и ф-ция принимает только копию этого значения, а в JavaScript-е ссылки на объекты являются значениями. Т.е. в данном случае, ты перезаписываешь копию ссылки аргумента(массива), из-за этого изменения не видны снаружи. Но если ты изменишь сам объект,а не ссылку (например arr.push(20)), то внешний массив изменится.

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterRange(arr, start, end) {
  return arr.filter(item => (item >= start && item <= end));
}
```